# How to grant user readonly access to GCS bucket folder via Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to grant user readonly permission on bucket with IAM condition , although i am able to do this via terraform/console but via Deployment manager its creating a user permission but not allowing me to set condition.
I am using this example from GCP https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/blob/master/dm/templates/iam_member/examples/iam_member_resource.yaml.
also when i grant user read access only on specific folder , user not able to list any objects in bucket in the folder ,for this i have to grant list object on all folders and read access to single folder

I tried to add IAM condition via deployment manager  on gcs bucket , it should add it but its not working

Comment: You can't list only the object granted with the IAM condition.

Comment: yeah it seems that in order to make it work , user should have get object permission without any IAM condition

Comment: You can list the object metadata, but with your IAM condition, the user will be able to read (download) only the matching object.